# How can you find a compiled bat (.exe) directory from within the batch file itself?

Tags: batch-file

I´ve compiled a .bat app into .exe, the problem is the app creates some results folders supposedly into the same directory, but as the .exe decompresses into the local Temp directory the results folder is being created there.
How can I keep the results in the same folder as my .exe?

Comment: I have tried  "%~dp0"  and  "%CD%"  but they both point into the Temp directory

Comment: You can't. This is a feature of whatever converter you're using. In the future, don't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can, and I did it, the rest of the "batch file content" and the compiler itself are meaningless to the issue, just use:

```
wmic process where "name='here.exe'" get ExecutablePath
```

Just iterate the results and set them into a variable:

```
for /f "tokens=2 delims=," %%I in (
    'wmic process where "name='here.exe'" get ExecutablePath^,Handle /format:csv ^| find /i "here.exe"') do set "exepath=%%~I"
```

Good night.

Comment: that just gets you the path of a file named `here.exe` (to be exact, the last finding, if there are several files with that name). There is no guarantee, that is the one that executed your batchfile. May work for you, but be aware of that.

Comment: You might be better off setting a custom window title and searching for that if you don't have a unique file name.